# Laravel 5 image upload issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and using laravel5.
Here is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image=$request->all();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->filePath = $name;
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
        Image::create($image);
    }      
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Here is my form:

```
{!! Form::text('title') !!}
{!! Form::text('description')!!}
{!! Form::file('image') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Save') !!}
```

Getting error "Attempt to assign property of non-object" in uploading. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: http://imgur.com/1DFirMo

Comment: could you please point it out what line 39 is?

Comment: $image->filePath = $name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **$image** is one of **Request instant**. And you are trying to get a object form **Request** which is not exist.

You need to make some change to you code, and this should works for you

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->all();

    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');

        //you also need to keep file extension as well
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //using array instead of object
        $image['filePath'] = $name;
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);

        Image::create($image);

    }      
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image=$request->all();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $image['image'] = $name; // This line has changed
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
        Image::create($image);
    }      
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: It added in mysql image field: D:\xampp\tmp\php470F.tmp

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $image=$request->all();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $image['image'] = $name;
        $file->move(base_path().'/images/', $name);    
    }      
    Image::create($image);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: It added in mysql image field: D:\xampp\tmp\php470F.tmp

Comment: `$name = $file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: Try this one `$name = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();`